# Creating Web Application in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: web-application

I installed & configured SharePoint Server 2016. When I  create new Web Application from Central Administration, I get an error message:

> Sorry something went wrong; There is no default endpoint for this
>   Application.

Comment: Are you working from PowerShell or the GUI?

Comment: From PowerShell

Comment: Check your logs. In most cases, this error means that the web application did not provision correctly. Depending on what you find in the logs, you may have to recreate the web app. This is common when working from PowerShell.

Comment: A good way to tell for sure is to try creating the web app via the GUI. If it works via the GUI, something is missing in your PowerShell script.

Comment: I recreated the web app and its working fine now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the configuration wizard? , did everything setup correctly you will have to look at it.

whether Central administration is up and running? .

Please check all the services started , check IIS manager and see if all App-pool are up and running.

You can also refer this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c2994496-781f-43c4-815a-59368d75b288/there-is-no-default-endpoint-for-this-application-error?forum=sharepointadmin)